# How to save exception to database from different module of the spring boot project?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Requirement:
Save exception to database using spring boot project from one module to different module.

Ex: Module 1 has code to save exception to database. when you throw any custom exception (eg. ResourceNotFoundInDatabaseException), parent exception class constructor having logic to save the exception message to database.

requirement: If I want to throw the same ResourceNotFoundInDatabaseException from other module 2 and in this time also I want to save the exception message to database.

I tried using as a dependency of module 1 to module 2. where I have imported the exception but it's not solve my problem. I was expecting to save the exception in same as module1 is able to do.

Comment: Did you try ExceptionHandler ? sample 

    `@ExceptionHandler(value = { ResourceNotFoundInDatabaseException.class })
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleIResourceNotFoundInDatabaseException(ResourceNotFoundInDatabaseException ex) {
        LOGGER.error("Resource Not Found In Database Exception: ",ex.getMessage());
        // call Repository with transaction REQUIRES_NEW
        return new ResponseEntity<Object>(ex.getMessage(),HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }`